# Find element if value is known

Tags: pandas

I have a series of movies with titles on the left and length on the right in ascending order:

```
title
I Just Want to Kiss You        11.0
We Were Once a Fairytale       11.0
The Salad Mixxxer              11.0
Oppressed Majority             11.0
The Laboratory of Fear         11.0
                              ...  
Dil To Pagal Hai              179.0
Come and Go                   179.0
A Bride for Rip Van Winkle    179.0
Phoonk                        179.0
Blue Is the Warmest Color     179.0
```

I want to find the 100th shortest movie in the above collection.
I tried to use iloc (as my prof suggested), I got the movie at the 100th place is 106 minutes long. But it doesn't give me the name of the movie.

Can someone suggest a solution, please? Thank you!

Comment: Try using `rank` something like this `df[df['length'].rank(method='min') == 100]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do double `[]`

```
df.iloc[[100]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I did use that to get the movie before asking but it was not the answer so I thought I was wrong. Thanks for confirming with me.